# composer.json in a Symfony bundle

Tags: json, symfony, composer-php

I've created a new Symfony bundle in our local git server which is working nicely. I'm using it in a new Symfony project, the bundle imported into the project using Composer to `vendor\Company\AppBundle`It depends on an external bundle so I made a `composer.json` file in the root of that bundle:

```
{
  "name": "Company/AppBundle",
  "description": "Application resources",
  "type": "symfony-bundle",
  "license": [
    "proprietary"
  ],
  "require": {
     "jms/metadata": "~1.1"
  }
}
```

Now I'd expect a `composer update` to get the `jms/metadata` package but it doesn't.

I import the `Company/AppBundle` in the following way:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "Company/AppBundle",
            "version": "2.1.2",
            "source": {
                "url": "git://github.com/guillaumepotier/parsley.js.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "2.1.2"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "Company/AppBundle": "*",
}
```

`composer list --tree` does show `Company/AppBundle` but doesn't list any dependencies under it.

`composer validate --with-dependencies` Doesn't have any relevant information.

Comment: What version of composer are you using? What output do you get with `composer show Company/AppBundle -i -t`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you added a `composer.json` file in `vendor/Company/AppBundle`. Modifying content in your `vendor` directory is never recommended. The `vendor` directory is also not used by composer to determine requirements (even in the case of a `path` repository, it is still the source that is read from, not the `vendor` directory).

I also do not understand how you managed to install your `Company/AppBundle` if it does not have a `composer.json` already. Can you please elaborate more about the hierarchy of your project/dependencies and which depends on what?

Comment: I import `Company/AppBundle` using the `composer.json` in the root of the project using:

`
"repositories": [

        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "Company/AppBundle",
                "version": "0.0.72",
                "source": {
                    "url": "http://git-srv.local/companybundles/appbundle.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
]
"require": {
        "Company/AppBundle": "*",
}
`

Comment: I've modified the `vendor/Company/AppBundle` to test if it would work but I do have master access to its repository.

It used to work perfectly as long as you manually required its dependencies but they've grown and we wanted to implicitly require them in the bundle itself.

Comment: Not sure why you are using the package type and not the vcs type. Manually maintaining the package type is a very cumbersome process, and it really should only be used for sources that simply cannot be included in a more preferred way. Since you own the source repo, you can simply add a composer.json to it and include it as a vcs repository type.

Comment: That fixed it. 
Importing `Company/AppBundle`  as `"type" : ""vcs"` instead of `"type" : "package"` let composer use the `composer.json` in that repo